# Modeling DDD aggregates – decide who is responsible for what

Tags: domain-driven-design, modeling, event-sourcing

after some time, I am still struggling to model my domain properly. Let me briefly introduce simplified background.

It is product monitoring SaaS. User needs to obtain a membership which defines his abilities and limits, let's call him a Member. Member can subscribe to products in order to keep track on product changes, and therefore being notified about it. Member can also create a group to which he can add subscribed products in order to customize notification behavior - "hey, in case of these products, notify me only if price drops more than 20%". Simply as that.

At first, I created three aggregates.

- ProductAggregate
- MembershipAggregate
- GroupAggregate

Even though my use case is fairly simply, I can't figure what is a proper way of modeling that.

1. Member can subscribe to products. Does "subscribe" method belongs to Membership or Product aggregate? Membership can exist without subscriptions, so is Product.
2. Member can create group – I would say it belongs to GroupAggregate, but membership limits (i.e. member can create max. 3 groups) needs to be checked. Group has no idea about that, so we need to load membership aggregate to check if it is possible.
3. As you see above, both cases require knowledge about membership limits, so it would be natural to place it all in membership aggregate. On the other hand, pretty much every action in the system will depend on user membership limits and thus everything would have to go through that aggregate – which is obviously bad.

The only solution I came up with is to build membership with method like "canCreateGroup()" etc. and retrieve that aggregate in command handler (application layer). So CreateGroupCommandHandler would do:

1. Load membership aggregate, execute canCreateGroup
2. Load group aggregate, execute CreateGroup

However, this way everything related to membership would be checked in application layer (command handlers) and I believe it is a domain responsibility, so it would be wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there's a requirement that no member ever breach their limits.  In that case, every operation that could possibly breach the limits has to run through the membership aggregate.  There's no way around that.

You can model the process of creating a group as its own process (with state, which enables resumption) in the domain, as in the saga pattern.  For a given member ID and group ID, the create group saga:

- attempts to add the group to the member's set of pending groups (the member validates that the group would not breach limits; note that this command has to be idempotent)
- if that succeeds, records that the member has approved creation of the group
- creates the group
- if that succeeds, records that the group has been created
- moves the group from the member's set of pending groups to the member's set of active groups
- if that succeeds, record that the group creation process has completed

The reservation process means that the failure mode would be a group which never gets created stays in pending and eventually prevents a member from creating more groups.  This situation can be detected by subscribing to the events from members (you seem to be event sourcing, judging from the tagging) and canceling (or perhaps resuming, depending on the interval) hung group creation attempts.